# Bootstrap navbar floating at the center on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap navbar is floating at the center on Wordpress not sure why.  Can anyone help me with this? Is it because of WordPress or my stylesheet problems?
(Will update my code here if you need)
[image]

**STYLE.CSS**

```
.navbar-default {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    position: fixed;
}
 .navbar-default .nav li a {
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
    color: #4aa5df;
    outline: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav >.active > a:hover {
    color: #4aa5df;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
     color: #777;
     background: transparent;
}
.logo {
    width: 190px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>           
</div>
</div>
```

Is working all fine on my html file but when i put it into Wordpress and came out with this problem!

Comment: Could you attach the relevant html and css?

Comment: @Passersby just updated my code on my question

Answer (score 0):

To put navbar-default at the top (which I'm assuming is what you want) you'd want to put:

```
.navbar-default {
    Position: fixed;
    Top:0;
    Left:0;
    Width:100%;
}
```

Or if you meant the content it would be the text align that was at fault!
Excuse the uppercase I'm responding on mobile!

Comment: I've tried your answer but still with no luck. The navbar shouldn't be floating and i want it to be navbar-fixed-top. Hope you can help me with this :)